# Rendering normal text with <math> tag in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, mathjax

I want to render the following content using angularjs

```
"The value of <math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML' style='background-color:#'> <semantics> <mrow> <munder> <mrow> <mi>lim</mi></mrow> <mrow> <mi>x</mi><mo>&#x2192;</mo><mfrac> <mi>&#x03C0;</mi> <mn>2</mn> </mfrac> </mrow> </munder> <msup> <mrow> <mrow><mo>(</mo> <mrow> <mi>sin</mi><mi>x</mi></mrow> <mo>)</mo></mrow></mrow> <mrow> <mi>tan</mi><mi>x</mi></mrow> </msup> </mrow> <annotation encoding='MathType-MTEF'>MathType@MTEF@5@5@+= feaahaart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBamXvP5wqonvsaeHbfrwDuv2yObqe euuDJXwAKbsr4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpe ea0xe9Lq=Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0=yqaqpepae9pg0Firpe peKkFr0xfr=xfr=xb9adbaqaaeaacaGaaiaabaqaaeGadaabaaGcba WaaCbeaeaaciGGSbGaaiyAaiaac2gaaSqaaiaadIhacqGHsgIRdaWc aaqaaiabec8aWbqaaiaaikdaaaaabeaakmaabmaabaGaci4CaiaacM gacaGGUbGaamiEaaGaayjkaiaawMcaamaaCaaaleqabaGaciiDaiaa cggacaGGUbGaamiEaaaaaaa@4A6C@ </annotation> </semantics></math> is"
```

Above content contains plain text along with `<math>` tag.

Here is what I want to achieve

**View File**

`<span ng-bind-html="content"></span>`

**Ctrl File**

```
$scope.content = "The value of <math xmlns = 'http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML' style = 'background-color:#' > <semantics> <mrow> <munder> <mrow> <mi>lim</mi></mrow> <mrow> <mi>x</mi><mo>&#x2192;</mo><mfrac> <mi>&#x03C0;</mi> <mn>2</mn> </mfrac> </mrow> </munder> <msup> <mrow> <mrow><mo>(</mo> <mrow> <mi>sin</mi><mi>x</mi></mrow> <mo>)</mo></mrow></mrow> <mrow> <mi>tan</mi><mi>x</mi></mrow> </msup> </mrow> <annotation encoding='MathType-MTEF'>MathType@MTEF@5@5@+= feaahaart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBamXvP5wqonvsaeHbfrwDuv2yObqe euuDJXwAKbsr4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpe ea0xe9Lq=Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0=yqaqpepae9pg0Firpe peKkFr0xfr=xfr=xb9adbaqaaeaacaGaaiaabaqaaeGadaabaaGcba WaaCbeaeaaciGGSbGaaiyAaiaac2gaaSqaaiaadIhacqGHsgIRdaWc aaqaaiabec8aWbqaaiaaikdaaaaabeaakmaabmaabaGaci4CaiaacM gacaGGUbGaamiEaaGaayjkaiaawMcaamaaCaaaleqabaGaciiDaiaa cggacaGGUbGaamiEaaaaaaa@4A6C@ </annotation> </semantics></math > is";
```

Here is what I am getting as Output

```
The value of lim x→ π 2 ( sinx ) tanx MathType@MTEF@5@5@+= feaahaart1ev3aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBamXvP5wqonvsaeHbfrwDuv2yObqe euuDJXwAKbsr4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpe ea0xe9Lq=Jc9vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0=yqaqpepae9pg0Firpe peKkFr0xfr=xfr=xb9adbaqaaeaacaGaaiaabaqaaeGadaabaaGcba WaaCbeaeaaciGGSbGaaiyAaiaac2gaaSqaaiaadIhacqGHsgIRdaWc aaqaaiabec8aWbqaaiaaikdaaaaabeaakmaabmaabaGaci4CaiaacM gacaGGUbGaamiEaaGaayjkaiaawMcaamaaCaaaleqabaGaciiDaiaa cggacaGGUbGaamiEaaaaaaa@4A6C@ is
```

You can view the expected output by simply saving the above content with .html extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using ngsanitize to mark the HTML as safe with ng-bind-html. Later I came to know that ng-bind-html functionality will validate Html using $sanitize. To bypass this validation, I Used

```
app.filter("trustHtml", ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return function (htmlCode) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlCode);
    }
}]);
```

and used it in view as

```
<span ng-bind-html="content" | trustHtml ></span>
```

Along with that, I used

```
<script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.0.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
    </script>
```

to render the `<math>` tag contents. Here, MathJax would require a refresh if any changes are done in `content`. Therefore, I used following to look out for changes

```
$rootScope.$watch(function () {
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub]);
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can split the content html into different parts, and filled in the html tag.such as

```
<span>The value of </span><math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'...></math><span>is</span>
```

Comment: I have thousands of such content in the database. Modifying each data will cost much time.

Comment: you can use the regex to match the keyword 'math'  and split the content

Comment: tried your answer, it's still loading the same output.

Comment: just put the <math xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'...></math> in the html。 make sure it wok。